# rspec/shoulda fails comparing two seemingly identical collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

(mentioning `shoulda` because I know it is in Gemfile - but don't know how it affects rspec tests, have no experience with it, don't know if it's involved here or not)

I have two [controller] tests:

first:

> it { should assign_to( :messages ).with(
>   current_user.messages.ordered.decorate ) }

and second:

> it { should assign_to( :messages ).with(
>   current_user.messages.order("send_at DESC").decorate ) }

note: the message.rb defines:

```
scope :ordered,     order( 'messages.send_at DESC' )
```

,so they are testing exactly the same thing - except that `ordered` method used to sort by a wrong field, and the first test would always pass, expected collection being the same as the actual; hence the 2nd test, which explicitly demands the correct sorting order.

Now, the madness: 1st test passes, 2nd test fails. Rspec prints:

```
 Expected action to assign #<DecoratedEnumerableProxy of
 MessageDecorator for [#<Message id: 1, ... >, <Message id: 2, ...>]>,
 but got #<DecoratedEnumerableProxy of MessageDecorator for [#<Message
 id: 1, ... >, <Message id: 2, ...>]>
```

You guessed it - the "expected.." and "but got.." parts printed here are absolutely identical. I've triple-checked them with diff. If both tests were failing, I would not be so perplexed, but 1st one passes, and 2nd one fails. I suspected that 1st test must be producing some kind of a side effect, but no, reordering or commenting out one of the tests doesn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm surprised no one has answered this one and it has me curious. The RSspec printouts of the expected/actual items are obviously summarized. Have you tried printing them out in more detail?

Comment: oh yeah I've printed them out exactly as they are, and they are literally the same. I've ran diff on them - they're not too huge, but too big to put them in here. Just take my word for it =) and diff's. I've triple-checked.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the `object_id` of each?

Comment: I have not - though once I have time to go back to that problem, I will try that.. yet it would seem counterintuitive for the matcher to care -- and it would be strange still to have one test behave differently from the other in that regard. But yes, I will remember to do that.